# Python: Catching Runtime Overflow in double_scalars

Tags: python, exception, overflow, physics, division

I'm currently doing a physics simulation of a rather esoteric system utilizing a RK4 algorithm.

It involves singularities (e.g. r -> 0), and divides by this radius in one of the equations. **There will be singularities, and I need the program to cease further calculations after this occurs.** I have built in a >break operation once the program gets too close to the singularity, but sometimes a user may not choose a good enough threshold value to break out before infinities arise. The value of this threshold cannot be determined beforehand - the system is markedly chaotic in dynamics. I have decided to attempt to catch the exception (specifically, *RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars*), so that the user is aware that their chosen singularity threshold is too low.

```
for i in range(indices - 1):
    try:
        if((theta0 == 0 or theta0 == pi) and i == 0):
            print('Unstable or stable equilibrium chosen as initial value. Please change the initial angle.')
            flag = True
            break
        if(variables[i][0] <= (singularitythreshold * r0)):
            print('The trajectory came within the threshold for identifying a singularity (%.5f%%). The program has finished early to avoid infinities.' % (singularitythreshold * r0 * 100))
            break
        k1 = step * RKaccel(variables[i], times[i])
        k2 = step * RKaccel(variables[i] + k1 / 2, times[i] + step/2)
        k3 = step * RKaccel(variables[i] + k2 / 2, times[i] + step/2)
        k4 = step * RKaccel(variables[i] + k3, times[i] + step)

        variables[i + 1] = variables[i] + k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6
    except RuntimeWarning:
        print('A Runtime Warning was triggered, indicating infinities as r -> 0. Increase the singularity threshold.')
        flag = True
        print('Plotting procedures have been abandoned to avoid nonsensical data.')
        break
```

I've read through 10+ posts about how to deal with this sort of issue (including seterr and seterrfunc), but I just can't seem to get it right. It never triggers the exception.

The calculating happens in RKaccel, and I don't think this function is relevant to catching the error so I didn't include it (lots of nasty equations). I have, however, included the specific warnings that get printed:

```
/tmpw0ojdH.py:35: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  radiusdotdot = ((radius / (1 + mu)) * ((thetadot) ** 2)) + (((g * cos(theta)) - (g * mu)) / (1 + mu))
/tmpw0ojdH.py:36: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  thetadotdot  = - ((g * sin(theta)) / radius) - (2 * ((radiusdot) * (thetadot)) / radius)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issues. The key was playing with seterr(). By adding

```
seterr(all = 'raise')
```

and changing

```
except RuntimeWarning:
```

to

```
except FloatingPointError:
```

My exception was triggered and all was fixed. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I'd be more useful if you said where to put seterr